# how to select a tag before a div with a class

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<a href="#">link1</a>
<a href="#">link2</a>
<div class="test">
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

I want to select the first a tag before div.test and add a class to it, so I tried this:

```
$('a').before('.test').addClass('test');
```

this works, but it also actually prints ".test" on the page.

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `.prev()`. And it is easy if you try to navigate from the div which has a class.

```
$('div.test').prev().addClass('test');
```

Comment: thanks. would be be possible to select a certain element specifically, for example if a tag is in p tag before a div, to target the a and not the p tag?

Comment: @OliveraKovacevic It is not available, because there is no way to locate this element when executing the first function in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `.prev()` instead of `.before()`.

[.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) actually inserts content, which is why `.test` is being printed out. It's still adding the class because of jQuery's chaining abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(".test").prev().addClass('test');`
I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TExJd/) while testing.